# emberjs with laravel pagination

Tags: laravel, ember-data, ember-cli

I am trying to load a paginated data, so far able to load the whole records.

Now not sure how to load the Laravel paginated data, as when I send call without pagination I get a response like

```
{
    'users':[{
        'id':1,
        'name':'Aamir'
     },{
        'id':2,
        'name':'Jamshed'
     }]
}
```

But when I enable pagination, there is a whole bunch of data with this, and ember starts to give an error

```
GET http://localhost:8000/api/users?citySef=Lahore&group=Ap
        200 OK
        87ms    
vendor.js (line 9861)
WARNING: Encountered "total" in payload, but no model was found for model name "total"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to be fixed on the laravel end,

```
    $city = blood_cities::where('sef' , '=', [$citySef])->get();

    $users = blood_users::where('city_id', '=',$city[0]->id)
        ->where( 'group', '=', $group  )
        ->paginate(15);

   $return = array(
        'users' => $users->items(),
        'meta'=> array(
            'total'=>$users->total(),
            'current_page'=>$users->currentPage(),
        )
    );
    return $return;
```

now ember will not give errors we will get the result.

**Update: 2015-05-25**

able to create pagination from http://blog.ksol.fr/paginated-apis-with-ember-js/